# Provide password to GitHub Actions macOS self-hosted runner

Tags: macos, sudo, github-actions

I have set up a CI build server using the GitHub Actions self-hosted runner instructions. Everything works fine until it reaches this instruction:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.5.app
```

it asks for my password inside the macOS Terminal. This defeats the purpose of a build server if I have to type in my password every single time this job runs. I've tried configuring the runner as a service but when I did that the job completely failed because it needs a terminal to ask for the password.

Is there a way to set the password so the runner stops asking me every single time?

Comment: You can use the `-S` flag and pipe in the password before the `sudo` command: https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line

Comment: However, it seems that `sudo` is password-less on macOS and Linux - see the documentation for more info: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners#administrative-privileges-of-github-hosted-runners

Comment: This seems to work. Yes when I run the job on a GitHub hosted runner it works fine without issues but when I run the job on my self-hosted runner it got stuck at the password prompt.

Comment: Was the solution to use -S? Or is there a better one?

Comment: @WilGieseler Yes the solution was to use -S

Answer (score -1):

You can try to remove the `sudo` command.

Comment: I tried that as well but the xcode-select command needs to be run as root.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me by editing the `visudo` file

> do use this with caution as you are making sudo passwordless

Editing visudo

```bash
╰─ sudo EDITOR=vi visudo
```

Commenting the `%admin` line and adding the following line

```bash
╰─ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep admin
# %admin                ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

In case you get locked out of sudo, the following will help.

[Locked out of sudo ?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317425/fixing-etc-sudoers-file)